# How can I make NSFetchedResultsController Update work with a UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, uisearchcontroller

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` displaying some data from Core Data and I'm trying to get a search bar working with it. The search works, but `controller(didChangeObject:)` is called with index paths from the full table, not the filtered one, so updating either modifies the wrong record or errors because the index path is out of range. Even though I know that this is the source of the error, I'm not sure how to fix it. The salient parts of my code are as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PlayerTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlayerTableViewCell
    let coreDataIndexPath: NSIndexPath
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        coreDataIndexPath = fetchedResultsController.indexPathForObject(filteredPlayers[indexPath.row])!
    } else {
        coreDataIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: coreDataIndexPath)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Fetch Record
        let record = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject

        // Delete Record
        managedObjectContext.deleteObject(record)
    }
}


// MARK: Fetched Results Controller Delegate Methods
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch (type) {
    case .Insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PlayerTableViewCell
            configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    case .Move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: UISearchResultsUpdating
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", searchText)
        if let fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [Player] {
            filteredPlayers = fetchedObjects.filter({return predicate.evaluateWithObject($0)})
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredPlayers.count
    } else if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0
}
```

`configureCell` just loads the data from the record at indexPath into the cell.

I had previously tried doing search by changing the `fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate`, but the table would not return to normal when the search bar was cancelled, despite my best efforts. That code was as follows:

```
// MARK: UISearchResultsUpdating
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", argumentArray: ["name", searchText])
    fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: UISearchBarDelegate
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = nil
    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you need to do here:

- reset the NSFetchedResultsController for each new search event in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`, before reloading the table data;
- return your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as the cell at the indexPath in the FRC. No need to poll the state of the searchBar, the NSFetchedResultsController will already be up-to-date.

I am not familiar with Swift syntax as of yet, but here is what it looks like in ObjC:

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext; // Creating FRC with main MOC

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSString *searchString = [self.searchController.searchBar.text];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ ", searchString];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Specify how the fetched objects should be sorted
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"someField" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
        NSLog(@"Error initializing FRC for Users. Error %@", error.userInfo);

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  }
return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil)
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        MyEntity *myObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    /* Populate cell content here */
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Just a note. The self.searchController can be tested for isActive property. So the fetchedResultsController initialisation part can contain just a condition for self.searchController.isActive with a body NSPredicate predicateWithFormat.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

This is your original predicate:

```
  var predicate: NSPredicate {
    return NSPredicate(format: "sampleCDAttribute == true")
  }
```

The text filter predicate:

```
  var searchTextPredicate: NSPredicate {
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text ?? ""
    let andPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "text CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)
    return NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate, andPredicate])
  }
```

The NSFetchRequest could have been included in FRC factory but has been extracted for readability:

```
  var request: NSFetchRequest<ManagedWord> {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<YourCDObject> = YourCDObject.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = predicate
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "text", ascending: true)]
    return request
  }
```

Your FRC declaration:

```
  //this is the container referencing from AppDelegate (customized)
  var container: NSPersistentContainer = AppDelegate.persistentContainer

  lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<YourCDObject> = {
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController<YourCDObject>(
      fetchRequest: request,
      managedObjectContext: container.viewContext,
      sectionNameKeyPath: "firstLetter",
      cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
  }()
```

UISearchResultsUpdating protocol:

```
extension YourViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    
    do {
      fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = text.isEmpty ? predicate : searchTextPredicate
      try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
      tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```